# how to implement .select2 and .multiselect feature at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want to make UI as in image 1 where user must see multiselect dropdown and can select multiple checkbox emails and also can mark only one email as Primary email id by clicking in right side as shown in the image 1. So basically 2 things are there 1-Can select multiple checkboxes dropdown emails and 2- Can select/Mark any one email as a primary email out of selected checkboxes emails.

Also, User should be able to type and search emails.
And if any emails which is not present in the dropdown then he should be able and add it as in image 2.

After that onSubmit i need to fetch all the selected email id and able to seperate Primary email id.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AVx7.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwC4r.png)

i did try with .multiselect jquery but only able to get multiselect dropdown and cannot add primary id selection feature and not able to add any emails which is not present in the dropdown.

Output image link- https://ibb.co/rdcZkVh https://ibb.co/rdcZkVh

```js
$('.share_quote_client_email').multiselect({
  placeholder: 'Select Emails',
  search: true,
  selectAll: true,
});

var options = $('#share_quote_modal_client_container').find('.ms-options').find('li');
if (options.length > 0) {
  options.each(function(index) {
    debugger;
    const htmlContent = '&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> <a href="#">Mark as Primary</a>';
    const existingLabel = $(this).find('label');
    existingLabel[0].innerHTML += htmlContent;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="shared_email_textbox spot_quote_email_drop_down share_quote_client_email" multiple>
  <option value="">Select Client</option>
  {% for client in clients %} '
  <option value="{{client.id}}" data-name="{{client.first_name}}" data-company_name="{{client.company_name|default_if_none:''}}" data-mobile_number="{{client.mobile_number|default_if_none:''}}" data-country_id="{{client.country_id}}" data-country_short_name="{{client.country_short_name}}"
    data-client-type="{{client.user_sub_type}}">{{client.email}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: You can change how select2 renders each drop down - so should not be too onerous to add a "mark as primary" button - I misread "clicking in right side" as "clicking with right mouse [and showing another popup]" - so my bad (images are blocked).

Comment: What have you tried?   What did you get stuck on?   Include your code in the question otherwise your "question" becomes a "do it for me" demand.

Comment: Please include the part of the code that you need help with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @freedomn-m I have edited the post with some codes. Actually I have used .multiselect and and then added primary mark looping in all the options li appending on it.   https://ibb.co/rdcZkVh  . But I also want if user types any new emails which is not present in options then they can add that. And this can be done using select2 tags. So how can i do it in .multiselect

Comment: re:edit - so you're using `.multiselect` - can you provide details as to which plugin that is?  (github/website/cdn).  So you're *not* using select2?

Comment: https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect   As of now i am not using select2. Because while i was using select2 i could not select multiple emails at once like in multiselect. I have to open dropdown everytime to select email in select2. @freedomn-m

Comment: I can use select2 if there is a way to achieve my functionality. its not like i have to use multiselect only.